# Using .tif on data layer for Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, geotiff-tiff

i have three files that i should use for a GIS application: map.aux, map.tfw, map.tif

The .tif file is a "layer" that highlights some building over a map.

How can i bring this information (and "image") on a layer of Google Maps? Any idea?

Comment: may be this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492967/georeference-tiff-image-into-the-google-map or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630868/can-a-tiff-formated-image-be-overlayed-onto-google-maps